# Elisp deep copying - consing

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to implement my own deep-copy routine in elisp (since something like `(setq newlist oldlist)` seems to give just a shallow copy, and `(copy-sequence newlist oldlist)` still leaves `newlist` exposed to any changes of the elements of `oldlist`)

Moreover, if there is a function that does what I want I am having no luck finding it.

The definition of my function is:

```
(defun deep-copy (iList oList)

    (setq oList (car iList))
    (setq counter (- (length iList) 1))
    (setq iList (cdr iList))
    (while (> counter 0)
        (setq oList (cons oList (car iList)))
        (setq iList (cdr iList))
        (setq counter (- counter 1) )))
```

and afterwards, with an `iList` of `(1 2 3 4 5 6)` what `oList` happens to have is: `(((((1 . 2) . 3) . 4) . 5) . 6)` 
i.e. nested lists.

I have tried quoting, back quoting, using append, switching the order of `oList` and `(car iList)` in `(cons # #)`, googling for a solution, but I am having no luck (either errors or garbage).

In addition to any welcome comments on what functions already exist that will do what I want, where there are weaknesses in the code (I am an elisp newbie), could someone tell me how to cons elements to an existing list properly?

the examples tend be variants of the form: `(cons 'pine '(fir oak maple))`, where `'(fir oak maple)` is some hard coded list

edit: For the last two hours I have been battling against myself (since I commented out oList in the calling function, and I kept referring to an old version of it). At any rate, swapping `oList` and `(car iList)` and then reversing at the end seems to do the trick (but surely there is a better way!?) i.e.

```
(defun deep-copy (iList)
  (setq oList nil )
  (setq counter (- (length iList) 1))
  (while (>= counter 0)
    (setq oList (cons (car iList) oList) )
    (setq iList (cdr iList) )
    (setq counter (- counter 1) ))
  (reverse oList)
    )
```

Comment: There's `copy-tree`, but it's never almost used.  Since you say you're an Elisp newbie, my guess is that you'd be better off asking how to do what you're doing *without* using a deep-copy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `copy-tree` (example assumes you `require`d `cl`, for my convenience, but `copy-tree` itself doesn't require it):

```
elisp> (setq list1 '(((1 2) (3 4)) 5 (6)))
(((1 2)
  (3 4))
 5
 (6))

elisp> (setq list2 (copy-sequence list1))
(((1 2)
  (3 4))
 5
 (6))

elisp> (setf (caar list2) 1)
1
elisp> list2
((1
  (3 4))
 5
 (6))

elisp> list1
((1
  (3 4))
 5
 (6))

elisp> (setq list1 '(((1 2) (3 4)) 5 (6)))
(((1 2)
  (3 4))
 5
 (6))

elisp> (setq list2 (copy-tree list1))
(((1 2)
  (3 4))
 5
 (6))

elisp> (setf (caar list2) 1)
1
elisp> list1
(((1 2)
  (3 4))
 5
 (6))

elisp> list2
((1
  (3 4))
 5
 (6))
```

Instead of giving tips about your code, I suggest that you read through the Elisp introduction that comes with Emacs: `C-h i g (eintr) RET` or other introductory Lisp books, for example [Touretzky](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf) (the latter is for Common Lisp, but a great introduction). It will teach you the basics – for example, to not just  `setq` in function definitions and so on.

But to give you an example, here's the definition of `copy-tree` (alternatively, just view it in your Emacs: `M-x find-function RET copy-tree RET`):

```
(defun copy-tree (tree &optional vecp)
  "Make a copy of TREE.
If TREE is a cons cell, this recursively copies both its car and its cdr.
Contrast to `copy-sequence', which copies only along the cdrs.  With second
argument VECP, this copies vectors as well as conses."
  (if (consp tree)
      (let (result)
    (while (consp tree)
      (let ((newcar (car tree)))
        (if (or (consp (car tree)) (and vecp (vectorp (car tree))))
        (setq newcar (copy-tree (car tree) vecp)))
        (push newcar result))
      (setq tree (cdr tree)))
    (nconc (nreverse result) tree))
    (if (and vecp (vectorp tree))
    (let ((i (length (setq tree (copy-sequence tree)))))
      (while (>= (setq i (1- i)) 0)
        (aset tree i (copy-tree (aref tree i) vecp)))
      tree)
      tree)))
```

Comment: Thanks, like I said to djf, I was confident something was already there for me but couldn't find it (hence re-inventing the wheel)...I agree that it will do me good to work through the elisp introduction, and will do this.

Comment: You're welcome. Have fun with the Elisp introduction! Learning Elisp in Emacs is great, since you can look at every Lisp function with `find-function`, modify (almost) everything at runtime, and explore in a live environment, that also happens to be thoroughly documented.

Answer (score 12):

Elisp has the function `copy-tree`. It's the recursive version of `copy-sequence`:

**Example**

```
(let* ((orig '((1 2) (3 4)))
       (copy (copy-tree orig)))
  (setcdr (cadr copy) '(0))
  (list orig copy))
==> (((1 2) (3 4)) ((1 2) (3 0)))
```

in your case you could write:

```
(setq oList (copy-tree iList))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I knew there had to be something coded up already but I just couldn't find it for myself...I have tried the function and (unsurprisingly) it works as I require it to